# How can I clear the EditText with onClick when the cursor is focussed on another EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two EditText widgets(editText1 and editText2) both has values populated by a button and the cursor is *focussed on editText1*. I have the listeners on both editText as shown in the code snippet below. With the *cursor on editText1*, it takes *two clicks/touch to clear editText2*. How can I clear editText2 with a single click/touch?

```
tipPercent.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            try{
                tipPercent.setText("");
            }
splitTip.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            try{
                splitTip.setText("");
            }
```

Screenshot of the EditText and click event

[image]

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: There was no error but it takes two clicks/touch to clear the textedit.

Comment: why you like to give right tick answer?

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
           //clear the edittext
        } else {
            //set the value when hasFocus is not
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tipPercent.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            splitTip.setText("");
        }
    }
});

splitTip.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            tipPercent.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The onFocusChange() is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question
you need to clear `editText2` when its focus? then you need to use `setOnFocusChangeListener` when `editText` get focus or lost focus you may clear `editText`

```
editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
           //clear editText when editext get focus

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //clear editText when editext lost focus
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. setOnFocusChangeListener() is what I was looking for, it works!

Comment: hope satisfy with answer, give right tick and up-vote

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
/*EditText1*/
tipPercent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tipPercent.setText("");
    }
});

/*EditText2*/
splitTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        splitTip.setText("");
    }
});
```

onFocusListener will work as this will allow you to clear the text in one click, as onClickListener is not made for this kind of purpose
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this //Kotlin

```
 private fun editTextClear(currentET: EditText, targetET: EditText) {
        currentET.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
        currentET.setFocusable(true)
        targetET.clearComposingText()
        targetET.setFocusable(false)
  }
```

//Now call this method onClick()

```
       first_et.setOnClickListener {
            editTextClear(first_et, second_et)
        }
        second_et.setOnClickListener {
            editTextClear(second_et, first_et)
        }
```

If you try to set `focusable="false"` for `second_et` you can single click on second_et from first time only to empty first_et

Hope this solves your problem